# What version of .NET comes with Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net

I just recently remoted into a dedicated server I recently got which is running windows server 2008.

I went into the Programs and Features and I don't see any .NET framework installed, but I know its running some version of .NET

Does anyone know what version of .NET windows server 2008 comes with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Vista and Server 2008 come with .Net 3.0. This includes the .NET 2.0 runtime (CLR) as well as the framework and library additions of 3.0 (WF, WCF, WPF).

Comment: LINQ isn't part of 3.0

Comment: @Daniel yeah, I'll remove it from the list.

Comment: Server 2008 R2 matches Windows 7, so includes .NET 3.5 SP1.
Also note that .NET 3.5 SP1 will be offered, via Windows Update, to Server 2008 and Vista machines.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked in the Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework folder and I'm seeing 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5

So I'm guessing it comes with all versions up to 3.5.

**UPDATE** I just read on a forum that Server 2008 R2 comes with .NET 3.5 SP1 as an installable feature.  I'm assuming that's why my build has it already.  Otherwise previous versions only install with .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.0 SP1

Comment: I have a fresh install + virtual-box guest add-ons. I looked in the folder you mention. It has 1.0.3705 1.1.4322, 2.0.50727. and in framework64 it has 2.0.50727.

Comment: there is an add feature button in Initial Configuration Tasks. That leads to a button to add .net 3.5.1